# Idiom for or more colorful phrasing of "without having their lack of trivia exposed"

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests, expression-choice

I am writing a children's book (8–12) and am looking for an idiom or more colorful language to be used in place of the highlighted section.

> Now that she’d stumped me, Ms. Sanders, my favorite of the Uniformed Division of the Secret Service and grand master of White House Trivia, would stop. And it’s a good thing too, since quite a line of employees have gathered behind me. They don’t mind waiting while she quizzes me on White House trivia since it means that they will get through **without having their lack of trivia exposed.**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing advice

Comment: Their ignorance intact from view?

Comment: *blissfully without having their ignorance of trivia exposed ...*

Answer (score 1):

You could use the idiom *scot-free*, though admittedly it's not a very colorful substitution in my opinion.

> They don't mind waiting while she quizzes me on White House trivia since it means that they will get through scot-free.

For something more colorful, maybe create your own simile/metaphor?  Example:

> They don't mind waiting while she quizzes me on White House trivia since it means that they will get through freely, like fearless mice scurrying past a sprung mousetrap.

Answer (score -1):

Since the work is for children and you presumably want to leave them a little better off than before they read your book, why not coin a word and define it parenthetically.  "  . . . since it means that they will get through without having their triviopenia, a lack of knowledge of trivia, exposed."